# how should I cook the steak at home

Tags: equipment, meat, grilling, steak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you cook a steak like those found in fine steakhouses?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/how-do-you-cook-a-steak-like-those-found-in-fine-steakhouses)

hi,

I have tried several times to cook steak at home but they were not as delicious and good as they were at restaurants. I used pan to cook that and just a little oil so that it wouldn't stick to pan. the heat was at the low level.

what is your advice on this? what type of equipment should I use? grill? thanks.

Comment: Please see our previous questions on this topic. In addition to the one marked as duplicate we also have [How do you properly cook a steak?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/267/41) and really the entire [steak tag](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steak).