# Steak qualities/beef grades in Canada?

Tags: beef, steak

In his [answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/3249/9471), @hobodave describes the three grades of beef available in the States: Select, Choice, and Prime. He further points out that most supermarkets only carry Select grade.

What are the grades available in Canada, and where can one find higher grades of beef?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grades that you would be interested in, that are available in Canada, are:
Prime, AAA, AA, and A

See:
[Beef Grades](http://www.beefgradingagency.ca/grades.html) and [Comparison with US Grades](http://www.canadabeef.ca/us/en/quality/Standards/default.aspx)

You can get [Sterling Silver Beef](http://www.sterlingsilvermeats.com/BeefBuyingTips.asp) in most grocery stores and it is either Prime or high quality AAA. It is also aged for 21 days.

You can also [order Prime on-line](http://www.montrealprime.com/xcart/catalog/Buy-Beef-Online-sp-26.html) or ask your favourite butcher.

Comment: Can you clarify whether Prime or A is on the side of the higher quality spectrum. Based on your answer it seems to imply Prime is the lowest quality and A is the highest which is confusing since Prime is the highest in the US.

Comment: The grades are listed from best to worst. Technically A is not a very good grade (it's below Select) but I included it because it is a 'youthful' grade (as opposed to 'mature').

Comment: You should make that clear in your answer. It's confusing since the OP listed the grades from worst to best.