# Stovetop Flank Steak

Tags: steak, stove

**Let me start with some background info:**

99% of the steaks I cook are <strike>strip</strike> skirt steaks because they are delicious and thin.  This makes them ideal for stovetop cooking.  I usually use a non-stick pan on high heat to brown each side, then medium for 5 minutes to cook the insides.  This works well enough for me, but isn't going to win me any medals.

**The Problem:**

I'm planning on making steaks for that special someone tomorrow and went to my local butcher today to pick up the skirts.  Unfortunately, they were unavailable, so I picked up a monster flank instead (~2.5 lbs).  I've had incredible flank steaks before, so I like the cut, but I've never cooked it.  The problem is two fold:

1) I assume I cannot cook it the same way as skirt

2) I'd like to aim a little higher on the culinary totem pole

**So my question to you is** what is the proper way to cook a Flank Steak on my stove or in my oven? Specifically, what are the differences I need to watch out for when preparing a thicker, larger steak.

**Some Extra Info:**

- I have a 12 in non-stick pan and 12 in flat cast iron pan at my disposal
- By "proper" I mean the method which will result in the most tenderness.  I've read through [this very helpful question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36854/what-makes-a-moist-steak) and [this one as well](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4568/what-are-other-techniques-are-used-to-tenderize-steaks-apart-from-using-a-meat-m) and certainly plan to take the advice provided.
- I have a wonderful dry rub that I plan on using (so no marinades as a mechanism for tenderizing)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mention strip and skirt in the first paragraph.  These are very different cuts.   Do you really mean skirt steak?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ whiips, thanks for pointing that out, I meant skirt, I'll update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way, imho, is to use your basic [broiling pan](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Broiler_pan.jpg)...Put a little water in the bottom before you start, or the pan may warp. Put the rack in your oven as high as it will go (while still allowing the broiling pan with steak to fit), then turn the oven on "Broil".

Leave the oven door cracked (you don't want it to pre-heat, and turn the element off), and cook it like you would on the grill, flipping it halfway through. The radiant heat from the element will give you a little char, though no grill lines, obviously.

Anything over medium rare is going to be a bit chewy. Let it rest, then cut it into strips across the grain of the meat. Flank steak responds well to marinades (my favourite: 1 tbps soy sauce, 1 tbsp sherry, 1 tbsp dijon mustard, 1 tbsp lemon juice, 1 tsp ground ginger.)

You could *try* to cook it on the stovetop, but that much meat will be too much for most pans.

Comment: Are dry rubs and broiling compatible?

Comment: @wnnmaw: It's pretty much the same as putting it on a grill. If you'd need to cook it at a lower temperature to keep your rub from going *flambe* then the same would apply in the oven.