# Is it possible to join two thin steaks together on the grill?

Tags: grilling, steak

I have some thinly cut rib eye steaks at home. I want to grill them but they get done too quick and I can't get that nice bite into them.

Is it possible to put one on top of another and grill them as if it was one thick piece? Will this work?

Answer (score 2):

It will not work. (*)

The two internal sides in the middle will steam and will not taste good.

I suggest to just cook them as quickly as possible in a hot pan.

(*) There is a chemical called "Transglutaminase" that acts like a meat glue that could be used to do that, but it is overkill.

Comment: Thanks. They are a centimetre wide. How long would they need in the grill pan so you think? Is it possible to get a medium sear?

Comment: @Zevi : it's counter-intuitive, but you need a *really* hot fire so that you sear the outside before the heat's had a chance to heat the inside significantly.  I would also recommend starting from a chilled state, and make sure that the outside is dry so it doesn't seam.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/29709/67

Comment: @joe clever that, I had them room temperature. Gonna try that, cheers.

Comment: @Zevi : And that should've been 'steam' not 'seam'.

Comment: Another option would be to pop them in a low oven on a rack - 200-250F - until they are about 20 degrees F below the target doneness, then slap them into the hottest pan you can for 30-60 seconds on a side until they brown. For this, I would use a regular skillet, not a grill pan.