# How to cook a 2-inch thick steak to medium?

Tags: steak

I have a striploin steak that's about 2 inches thick. I'm going to sear it in a hot pan on all sides. And then put it in the oven to cook it.

I want it to come out medium to medium-well.

How long do I need to bake it for and at what temperature?

Comment: I think this question is hard to answer exactly. The easiest way to estimate the duration of the steak in the oven is to cook the steak at ~260°C and after >3 minutes each side (altogether >6 minutes) and then measure the inner temperature of the steak. 57-60°C should be medium rare. Of course this his method requires a thermometer. (source: [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1424/23376) and [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/286/23376)).

Comment: @ChingChong It's fine to post things like that as answers - though it sure seems like there must be something we can close this as a duplicate of. "You need a thermometer" is pretty common advice.

Comment: Okay. I'm always unsure whether my advice "I don't know, the common way to do is is this workaround: ..." should be an answer (which doesn't really answers the question) or a comment.

Comment: Some restaurants slow cook with a timer, put the steak on ice and then brown it on the grill before serving it. I don't know how they stop it from drying. Basting with honey might work. Or pre-cook in a bag as per the question I just noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is hard to answer exactly. The easiest way to estimate the duration of the steak in the oven is to cook the steak at ~260°C and after >3 minutes each side (altogether >6 minutes) to measure the inner temperature of the steak. 57-60°C should be medium rare. Of course this his method requires a thermometer. (source: [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/1424/23376) and [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/286/23376))