# How do I stop my steak from leaking juice?

Tags: steak, frying-pan

I panfry the steak by searing on high both sides, then cook it at a low-medium temperature until medium rare. Then I let the steak rest for ~10 minutes before cutting it. During that time a lot of juice leaks out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: About how much juice are you seeing?  A couple tablespoons?  Also, about how thick are your steaks?

Comment: Where are you resting it? What temp are you cooking it to?

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/267/how-do-you-properly-cook-a-steak

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people had good questions in the comments. The best being Kenji's article from serious eats .com. Read that.

Chances are if a lot of juices are coming out of your steak, its because you are cooking it past medium. I like to think the proportion of 'grey' meat in a cooked steak indicates how much red juice has been 'squeezed' out of the meat fibrils and is now on the plate. If your steak is still medium or medium rare, there is lots of 'red' meat that has the capacity to hold the juice!
-Most important: Let rest ten minutes (longer for bigger cuts/roasts etc) after cooking. Seems like you're doing that.

Heres one link to a Serious Eats article by Kenji. This one explains some myths, including 'locking in juices'.

[Serious Eats - Steak Old Wives Tales](http://www.seriouseats.com/2013/06/the-food-lab-7-old-wives-tales-about-cooking-steak.html)

Comment: You could link to that article. That'd make your suggestion to read it more useful.

Comment: Good point @derobert. -Edited

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Heating meat proteins makes them contract, which squeezes out water which was previously happily trapped between them. You can't avoid some of this happening at any temperature - the only way to not lose any moisture at all is to not cook the meat.

As you sear it, the outside obviously gets very hot, the water boils out and the delicious browning happens. The interior begins to warm, and as you reduce the heat and then as you rest it it's still rising in temperature up to the point you want to serve it. All that time the proteins are contracting - quite gently, if you're cooking it to, say, medium-rare - and water will come out. Just less than would if you went to well done all the way through!

If you're making a sauce to go with your steak, put the juices from resting it into the sauce for extra beefy flavour. Assuming it's that kind of sauce anyway.

Unless the steak seems dry or tough you're not doing anything wrong at all. There will always be some moisture loss and you simply can't avoid it - but you can minimise it within the boundaries of how you like your steak cooked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, your method seems fine. Steak has a lot of juice in it and it's entirely normal to have some juice come out of a steak while resting. If there wasn't juice I'd be worried.

Answer (score 0):

Let your steak sit out until room temperature. Pre-heat your oven to 350°F. Pre-heat your frying pan to searing hot. Pat dry your steak with paper towel and rub each side with salt. Put the steak in the pan and sear each side for 1m. Put the steak into the oven for about 5m (depending on thickness). Let it rest on the counter for 10m.

An alternative which keeps 100% of the juice is to cook it [sous vide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-vide). That might be too juicy for you though!

Answer (score -4):

Probably because temperature of the pan is too low when you place in it.
Steaks should have a high temperature shot at the beginning of cooking so the meat is slightly charred and seals inside the juice. The blood is clotted and the water keeps the meat tender.

Comment: Searing meat does NOT in fact "seal in the juice". Turns out it's a myth. http://www.seriouseats.com/2009/12/the-food-lab-how-to-cook-roast-a-perfect-prime-rib.html?ref=search and http://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/5699-searing-steak

Comment: Will try, but in Italy, where I live, normally when cooking 2 or 3 lbs. " fiorentina " steaks we burn them on wood (no flame) and then cut quickly to eat with the inside red. If someone wants the meat well done, after cutting some slices we continue the cooking until done. The idea of heating meat at about 50 ° C could be good but generally keeping meat at high temperatures for prolonged time causes hardening of it.

Comment: @ krufra When you cook a thick steak like that, the inside stays cool meaning the muscle fibers have yet had the time to contract and squeeze out the juice. It doesn't mean that searing seals anything in.

Comment: @user2052413 The charring of exterior reduces water content of the exterior thus increases thermal resistance. This keeps interior cooler because  energy required to increase internal temperature is shielded.  Flavor is generally related to volatile substances so if you keep meat at high temperatures for long times you will surely lose some flavor not only juices. For this reason if you like well done meat you should cook thin slices, losing some flavor.

Comment: Actually, boiling off the water on the outer layer takes a significant amount of energy (water has a huge specific heat capacity compared to many common substances), which insulates the interior. Once that's done, the heat can get to the interior much more readily. But by that point the outside's ascended to the necessary temperature to brown nicely (which can't happen until after the water is gone) and you're taking it off the heat.