# Safe to leave meat out for a couple of hours?

Tags: food-safety, raw-meat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it dangerous to eat meat which has been left out and then cooked?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12992/why-is-it-dangerous-to-eat-meat-which-has-been-left-out-and-then-cooked)

On Friday I am picking up some food items that I won't be able to get to a fridge and/or freezer for at least a couple of hours. I am not worried about the fruit or vegetables but I am also picking up some meat (specifically ground beef, round steak and pork tenderloin). The meat will be completely frozen upon pickup.

My question is will the meat still be good if I get home a couple hours later? In addition could I put the meat in the freezer or must I put it in the fridge and it eat within X days. Also are there any signs I should watch? For example if meat is still cold to touch and is firm I can still put it in the freezer with no problems.

Thank you

Comment: See also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4018/60

Comment: I'm not so certain this is a duplicate -- I've heard of some farmers markets selling hard-frozen meat, and it'd be good to know if it's safe to re-freeze, and what sort of time frame we have to transport it before we need to worry.  (vs. dealing with meat that's only at fridge temperatures)